# Bash string comparison does not eval to true

Tags: string, bash, comparison

I have a script where I want to find out the status code of a HTTP request. However, the `if` statement never evaluates to true and I don't understand why.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

CURL='/usr/bin/curl'
CURL_ARGS='-o - -I -s'
GREP='/usr/bin/grep'

url="https://stackoverflow.com"

res=$($CURL $CURL_ARGS $url | $GREP "HTTP/1.1")

echo $res # This outputs 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'
echo ${#res} # This outputs 16, even though it should be 15

if [ "$res" == "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ]; then # This never evaluates to true
  echo "It worked"
  exit 1
fi

echo "It did not work"
```

I checked the length of `res` and it was 16, I checked it in the browser's console and it was 15 so I trimmed it by removing whitespace on both ends but still it did not evaluate to true.

```
res_trimmed="$(echo "${res}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"
```

It still doesn't work.

What could be wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, it's bad form to store command fragments in string variables. See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: Also, since your shell is `/bin/sh` rather than `bash`, you can't assume that `==` is valid -- the [POSIX sh standard only specifies `=` as a string comparison operator](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html). (Also, you should probably be tagging your questions `sh` rather than `bash` if that's intentional).

Comment: (POSIX *also* indicates that the all-caps variable namespace is used for variables with meaning to the OS or shell, and reserves lowercase names for application use -- see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph).

Comment: (`GREP='/usr/bin/grep'` is also considered an antipattern these days, and not just because of the variable case. Modern shells -- meaning the last 30 years' worth -- cache PATH lookups, so there's no significant performance gain there, but there *is* a portability hit since the decision whether to put a given binary in `/bin` or `/usr/bin` tends to vary between distros).

Comment: ...btw, in bash, `printf '%q=%q\n' res "$res"` will give you a much more accurate description of what exactly is *actually in* the variable named `res`. (`declare -p res` works too in bash 4.x, and adds extra detail about variable type and flags, but in some 3.x shells it would emit certain nonprintable characters literally rather than escaping them; if one of those characters is your culprit, that's not so helpful).

Comment: ...also, see [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) regarding `set -e` (skipping the parable for the exercises below if in a hurry). It's... not exactly universally considered good practice to use.

Comment: BTW, note that `exit 1` is a failure -- only `0` is success. (This is the same as for constants passed to the `exit` function in C).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better-practice implementation might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- ensure that you have bash extensions available, rather than being
#                    only able to safely use POSIX sh syntax. Similarly, be sure to run
#                    "bash yourscript", not "sh yourscript".

set -o pipefail  # cause a pipeline to fail if any component of it fails

url="https://stackoverflow.com"

# curl -f == --fail => tell curl to fail if the server returns a bad (4xx, 5xx) response
res=$(curl -fsSI "$url" | grep "HTTP/1.1") || exit
res=${res%$'\r'}  # remove a trailing carriage return if present on the end of the line

if [ "$res" = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ]; then
  echo "It worked" >&2
  exit 0            # default is the exit status of "echo". Might just pass that through?
fi

echo "It did not work" >&2
exit 1
```

Comment: ...btw, `if curl --fail "$url"; then echo "success"; else echo "failure"; fi` might actually suffice, without needing to grep the output at all, if you just want to know if the result does or does not reflect a HTTP error.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you are getting stray characters in the return from your *command substitution*. To eliminate, only match valid characters, e.g.

```
GREP='/usr/bin/grep -o'
...
res=$($CURL $CURL_ARGS $url | $GREP 'HTTP/1.1[A-Za-z0-9 ]*')
```

other change

```
echo "'$res'" # This outputs 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sh curltest.sh
'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'
15
It worked
```

Comment: Specifically, the `curl`s output generally has DOS/Windows-style line endings, with a carriage return followed by linefeed. Unix tools treat the carriage return as part of the line (that 16th character).

Comment: This *does* solve the OP's question as narrowly interpreted, but it's also not exactly showcasing best practices.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What would be best practices for this? A link to documentation or an SO post would be appreciated.

Comment: @simeg, ...I've added a separate answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes agreed, (had to run pick kids up...). The BASH FAQ/50 link addressed the fragment issue. Originally the interpreter constrained the answer to POSIX, but as you show there are a number of changes that can improve handling and more with bash.

Comment: To ensure that this is correct and complete as a pure-POSIX solution, should specify `=` vs `==` to guarantee support for ash/dash.

Comment: God love that attention to detail. Thanks Charles. (I just flat missed that `:)`